# How to convert string to date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, procedure

I have a table named `UserLog` as shown here. How can I write a procedure to find the specified data in the table?

I have created the following procedure; but it doesn't work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_CleanUserLogTable]
    @FromDate date,
    @ToDate date
AS
    DELETE FROM UserLog 
    WHERE TRY_CAST(EnterDate AS date) >= @FromDate 
      AND TRY_CAST(EnterDate AS date) <= @ToDate
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFa4v.png)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also - be more specific than *it doesn't work* - what happens? Nothing at all? It's deleting the *wrong data*? It's throwing an error? If so: *what* error? Remember - we cannot see your screen, nor read your mind - you need to **TELL and SHOW US!**

Comment: Thanx dear for your information. when I execute the procedure (exec Sp_CleanUserLogTable '2021-09-20', '2021-09-21') it gives me the result: (0 row(s) affected); but indeed the table has more than 20 records at that period

Comment: What happens when you use `CAST()` instead of `TRY_CAST()`?

Comment: And what happens when you use `datetime` instead of `date`?

Comment: And what datatype is the `date` column from the `UserLog`?

Comment: Using CAST(): Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Using datetime: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserLog](
 [UserLogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ComputerName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [IPAddress] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [EnterDate] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [ExitDate] [nchar](50) NULL,
 [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,

Comment: select * From UserLog where   Format(EnterDate,'yyyy-MM-dd') > '2021-09-21'

Comment: in select case it shows this error: Argument data type nchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.

Comment: 1) [edit] any addition info into your question 2) Thats the table definition, we need sample data that will reproduce the issue.

Comment: I sent you some of its records as an image by editing question

Comment: `[EnterDate] [nchar](50) NOT NULL` This is your real problem. Fix your schema. Storing dates as string will continue to a problem for the lifetime of this system and will tax the performance of that system since it must be converted to be used as an effective filter. At some point the column will contain invalid values and values in a different format. TRY_CONVERT will simply ignore (or incorrectly convert) them - is that a good thing? You decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [date format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) that exactly matches your text, but you can use `REPLACE` to get a different format:

```
TRY_CONVERT(datetime, REPLACE(EnterDate, '.', '-'), 105)
```

This is one of the many reasons why you should *always* store data in the correct data type in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Format the date as `yyyy-MM-dd`. eg `2021-09-23`